# Oracle: Syntax for multiple lateral joins or applys

Tags: oracle, lateral-join

I am trying to get the syntax for a series of lateral joins in Oracle.

I have an `authors` table with the author’s `id`, `name` and `home`; I have a `books` table with an `id`, `authorid` which is a foreign key to `books(id)`, a `title` and `price`.

I want to use lateral joins to calculate the tax (`price*0.1`) and the inclusive price (`price+tax`), as well as to include the author’s name and home.

Here is a version that works in PostgreSQL and MySQL:

```sql
SELECT
    id,title,
    price, tax, inc,
    givenname, othernames, familyname,
    home
FROM books
    JOIN LATERAL(SELECT price*0.1) AS sq(tax) ON true
    JOIN LATERAL(SELECT price+tax) AS sq2(inc) ON true
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL(SELECT givenname,othernames,familyname FROM authors
        WHERE authors.id=books.authorid) AS sw2 ON true;
```

Here’s the same thing in MSSQL:

```sql
SELECT
    id,title,
    price, tax, inc,
    givenname,othernames,familyname,
    home
FROM books
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT price*0.1) AS sq(tax)
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT price+tax) AS sq2(inc)
    OUTER APPLY(SELECT givenname,othernames,familyname,home FROM authors
        WHERE authors.id=books.authorid) AS sw2;
```

I understand that Oracle has the `CROSS APPLY` and `OUTER APPLY` syntax, as well as the more standard `LATERAL` syntax. I also know about the following oracle quirks:

- `SELECT … FROM dual`
- you can’t use `AS` for table aliases

I have tried every combination of syntax I can think of but I keep getting cryptic errors such as `SQL command not properly ended` or `MISSIING KEYWORD` or something equally illuminating.

What is the correct syntax for this sort of query.

**Note**

I know that there are other ways to get the same result, and that it’s a trivial example. This is a question about how to write lateral joins in Oracle.

**Update**

OK, here’s the answer:

Oracle doesn’t like the syntax:

```sql
(SELECT price*0.1) sq(tax)
```

It prefers the alias to be in the subquery:

```sql
(SELECT price*0.1 AS tax)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of lateral join here? It's more like lookup function that may return a dataset instead of scalar, but it's not the case here. `... lateral (select x.column * constant)` (which should be rewritten as explicit cross join instead of artificial `true`) should rather be placed in the select list as a standalone expression. It would be much clearer and (possibly) faster. Thus, your *current* code may use plain join and calculations in the `select` list expressions

Comment: @astentx The purpose is just to understand more about the lateral join syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use a `LATERAL` join then:

```sql
SELECT b.id,
       b.title,
       b.price,
       t.tax,
       i.inc,
       a.givenname,
       a.othernames,
       a.familyname,
       a.home
FROM   books b
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL(SELECT price*0.1 AS tax FROM DUAL) t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL(SELECT price+tax AS inc FROM DUAL) i
       LEFT OUTER JOIN authors a
       ON a.id=b.authorid;
```

*Note: `authors` does not need to be a `LATERAL` join, and `OUTER` join is sufficient.*

However, you don't need to use a `LATERAL` join:

```sql
SELECT b.id,
       b.title,
       b.price,
       b.price * 0.1 AS tax,
       b.price * 1.1 AS inc,
       a.givenname,
       a.othernames,
       a.familyname,
       a.home
FROM   books b
       LEFT OUTER JOIN authors a
       ON a.id=b.authorid;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE books ( id, title, price, authorid ) AS
  SELECT 1, 'How to cook 4 humans', 42, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Mannequin Maintenance: For Dummies', 3.99, 2 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE authors ( id, givenname, othernames, familyname, home ) AS
SELECT 1, 'A', 'Large', 'Monster', 'Cave' FROM DUAL;
```

Both queries output:

| ID | TITLE | PRICE | TAX | INC | GIVENNAME | OTHERNAMES | FAMILYNAME | HOME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | How to cook 4 humans | 42 | 4.2 | 46.2 | A | Large | Monster | Cave |
| 2 | Mannequin Maintenance: For Dummies | 3.99 | .399 | 4.389 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BKtWFuTx)

Comment: I agree that it might be better without the lateral joins. I just wanted to learn more about the syntax. BTW I like the Twilight Zone references.